# Subtract successive rows for each Year in a dataframe grouped by ID in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (mydf) with Sales organised by ID in a monthly YTD format. Only one group/ID is shown as an example, however data contains several such IDs.

```
    Date        ID      Sales
    2020-01-01  B0118   63975
    2020-02-01  B0118   114568
    2020-03-01  B0118   202849
    2020-04-01  B0118   280112
    2020-05-01  B0118   336854
    2020-06-01  B0118   377005
    2020-07-01  B0118   437183
    2020-08-01  B0118   517220
    2020-09-01  B0118   589187
    2020-10-01  B0118   632946
    2020-11-01  B0118   701808
    2020-12-01  B0118   766152
    2021-01-01  B0118   57883
    2021-02-01  B0118   99555
    2021-03-01  B0118   190112
    2021-04-01  B0118   289180
    2021-05-01  B0118   338044
    2021-06-01  B0118   373061
```

Except for the first month, I need to deduct the sale by year from each row with the prior row. For example, the sale for 2020-02-01 should be deducted from the previous month's sale (2020-01-01), and so on, whereas the sale for 2020-01-01 should remains the same as it is the first month.

Excepted output should look like:

```
    Date        ID      Sales   dif
    2020-01-01  B0118   63975   63975
    2020-02-01  B0118   114568  50593.0
    2020-03-01  B0118   202849  88281.0
    2020-04-01  B0118   280112  77263.0
    2020-05-01  B0118   336854  56742.0
    2020-06-01  B0118   377005  40151.0
    2020-07-01  B0118   437183  60178.0
    2020-08-01  B0118   517220  80037.0
    2020-09-01  B0118   589187  71967.0
    2020-10-01  B0118   632946  43759.0
    2020-11-01  B0118   701808  68862.0
    2020-12-01  B0118   766152  64344.0
    2021-01-01  B0118   57883   57883   
    2021-02-01  B0118   99555   41672.0
    2021-03-01  B0118   190112  90557.0
    2021-04-01  B0118   289180  99068.0
    2021-05-01  B0118   338044  48864.0
    2021-06-01  B0118   373061  35017.0
```

To start with, I am trying something like but I need the difference by Year:

```
mydf['dif'] = mydf.groupby('ID')['Sales'].diff(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get yearly diff you can create a new column year from the Date.

```
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.year
```

Next, you can use ID and Year to get the desired result

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Year'])['Sales'].diff().fillna(df.Sales)
```

Output:

```
          Date     ID   Sales  Year     diff
0   2020-01-01  B0118   63975  2020  63975.0
1   2020-02-01  B0118  114568  2020  50593.0
2   2020-03-01  B0118  202849  2020  88281.0
3   2020-04-01  B0118  280112  2020  77263.0
4   2020-05-01  B0118  336854  2020  56742.0
5   2020-06-01  B0118  377005  2020  40151.0
6   2020-07-01  B0118  437183  2020  60178.0
7   2020-08-01  B0118  517220  2020  80037.0
8   2020-09-01  B0118  589187  2020  71967.0
9   2020-10-01  B0118  632946  2020  43759.0
10  2020-11-01  B0118  701808  2020  68862.0
11  2020-12-01  B0118  766152  2020  64344.0
12  2021-01-01  B0118   57883  2021  57883.0
13  2021-02-01  B0118   99555  2021  41672.0
14  2021-03-01  B0118  190112  2021  90557.0
15  2021-04-01  B0118  289180  2021  99068.0
16  2021-05-01  B0118  338044  2021  48864.0
17  2021-06-01  B0118  373061  2021  35017.0
```